# SQL Summing a column value based conditional on another table's value

Tags: table

I'm working on a SQL query that returns a SUM of a value in a column/table based off a related value in another table's column being met. I'm getting an error:

*The multi-part identifier "Charges.JR_LocalSEllAmt" could not be bound. The multi-part identifier "Filtered.ChargeFAF" could not be bound.*

Are you able to see anything clearly wrong with my code below? I'm unsure about how to access the AccChargeCode tables column values to check the condition before returning a SUM from a column within the Job Charge table.

```
SELECT  Charges.Filtered.ChargeFAF AS ChargeFAF
LEFT JOIN dbo.JobHeader ON LTC_PK = JH_ParentID
LEFT JOIN dbo.JobCharge ON JH_PK = JR_JH AND JR_OSSellAmt > 0
LEFT JOIN dbo.AccChargeCode ON JR_AC = AC_PK

LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            JR_JH,
            JR_LocalSellAmt,
            JR_AC
        FROM
            dbo.JobCharge
            
            LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                AC_PK,
                AC_Code,
                SUM(CASE WHEN AC_Code = 'LTFAF' THEN Charges.JR_LocalSellAmt ELSE 0 END) AS ChargeFAF       
                FROM
                    dbo.AccChargeCode
                GROUP BY
                    AC_PK,
                    AC_Code
            ) AS Filtered ON Filtered.AC_PK = JR_AC
        GROUP BY
            JR_JH
    )  AS Charges ON Charges.JR_JH = JH_PK
```

Comment: What database system and version?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. See code for comments.

```
SELECT 
    ChargeFAF = 
        Charges.ChargeFAF /* Remove .Filter */
FROM dbo.SomeTable /* You were missing a FROM here */
LEFT JOIN dbo.JobHeader 
    ON LTC_PK = JH_ParentID
LEFT JOIN dbo.JobCharge 
    ON  JH_PK = JR_JH 
    AND JR_OSSellAmt > 0
LEFT JOIN dbo.AccChargeCode 
    ON JR_AC = AC_PK
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        JR_JH,
        JR_LocalSellAmt,
        JR_AC,
        ChargeFAF 
        /* You need to select this 
           column here to reference 
           it in the outer SELECT */
    FROM dbo.JobCharge        
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
        AC_PK,
        AC_Code,
        ChargeFAF = 
            SUM
            (
                CASE 
                    WHEN AC_Code = 'LTFAF' 
                    THEN Charges.JR_LocalSellAmt 
                    ELSE 0 
                END
            )       
        FROM dbo.AccChargeCode
        GROUP BY
            AC_PK,
            AC_Code
    ) AS Filtered 
      ON Filtered.AC_PK = JR_AC
    GROUP BY
        JR_JH
)  AS Charges 
   ON Charges.JR_JH = JH_PK;
```